# ServerSocket на Heroku

Tags: java, сокет, heroku

Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу подключиться к серверному сокету на хероку.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(System.getenv("PORT"));

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server running " + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + " port...");
        //куча весёлого кода
   }    
}
```

Подключаюсь с помощью

```
Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);
```

Получаю

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

Сервер может к себе подключиться без проблем, но извне уже проблемы.
Как исправить? Возможно ли вообще на хероку к серверным сокетам подключаться?

Comment: Дины обрабатывают только http-трафик.

Comment: Т.е. на хероку никак?

Comment: Да, искать полноценный хостинг, а не PaaS.

Answer (score 0):

Код должен иметь строку (и возможно, в бесконечном цикле):

```
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
```